# Doubt about an inequality

Tags: inequality

I think this inequality holds but I don't menage to prove it. $$ \sum_{\pi=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{n_K^\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \le \sqrt{mK} $$
with: $$ \sum_{\pi=1}^{m}n_K^\pi = K $$
can anyone help me? As I told you I'm not sure this is true.

Comment: Did you really have to sum over $\pi$? 

Comment: Yes, maybe I could have changed the notation xD. However maybe I did this. One proves $\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{n}^{n_K^i} \sqrt{1/n} \le \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{n}^{K/m} \sqrt{1/n}  \le m\sqrt{K/m}$..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality is wrong: Try $m=1$ and $n^1=2$. Then the left-hand side is $1+\frac1{\sqrt2}$ which is more than the right-hand side $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: yes, but this can't be.. What about if $m > 1$ ?

Comment: What about my argument?

Comment: @Peanojr Try for example $m=n^1=n^2=2$ and it is also wrong

Comment: @Peanojr I think both inequalities in your argument are wrong in general